# Best way to syncing two different database

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-administration

I have two database(SQL Server) one database has 2.5 million records and the other one is empty, i want to transfer data from first one to the second one and after that every time first database has been changed the second database must sync. And we must do it in offline way with excel file for example(there is no online way between them) , Can anyone show me a guideline to do this?

Comment: There are many articles on the subject. MS: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/synchronize-data?view=sql-server-ver15. 3rd party: https://www.toptal.com/sql/guide-to-data-synchronization-in-microsoft-sql-server

Comment: Second database is only for reading? Or it would be updated too? You are saying no online sync possibility between them, right? As if you need to carry the changes in a USB stick or so? Probably easiest would be to create a backup and restore on the other.

Comment: @CetinBasoz   second database must update too. yeah there is no online way, we export first data base to excel file and in second database import from the excel file, now we have near 3 million records in first database that would be transfer by this excel file. we concern about server heavy loading to read 3 million records first time for inserting in second data base and 3 million each time for updating from excel file

Comment: 3 million insertion is not a problem really, using SqlBulkCopy you can complete in a minute or less. Rest of your problem is not understandable (how would you handle collisions, data edited on both sites ...).

Comment: Check Change_Tracking in SQL Server docs. That might help you for a starter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only one out-of-the-box solution for offline replication, ie that doesn't require a network connection from the the distributor to the publisher and from the subscriber to the distributor or distributor to subscriber.

[Snapshot Replication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/snapshot-replication?view=sql-server-ver15) with [Alternate Snapshot Location](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/snapshot-options?view=sql-server-ver15#alternate-snapshot-locations).  You take a snapshot of the published tables, copy the snapshot *somehow* to a location visible to the subscriber, and then apply the snapshot from the new location.

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to do that but I think the easiest could be replication, you can use Transactional replication or snapshot replication.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/transactional/transactional-replication?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Don't think that meets the "And we must do it in offline way" requirement?

Comment: @DaleK I don't think the OP understands that `And we must do it in offline way` with Excel isn't exactly practical. Replication *can* work "offline" - you can even distribute snapshots with CDs. If anything, this subject is far too broad for a SO question

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I was more pointing to the fact that we don't understand what the OP is asking enough to be giving answers, and that any answers provided should really include the details of how the answers the OP's question rather than just contain a link.

Comment: @DaleK I agree - besides, *replication* itself isn't trivial

Comment: @AminPashna what makes you think I don't know how to do it? You've posted a link with no additional guidance on how it answers the question. Link only answers are not encouraged on StackOverflow. In order to help the OP solve their problem you need to add some text which which gives them an idea what they are looking for - like David did.